# got the data pulled but can't print the table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I been working on this web scraping example tutorial for 5 days so far. I am happy with the results and I've been able to overcome the problems so far and I get the scraping data, i have the loop working and can pull it in the console. The problem comes with pulling that data into pandas or any kind of export type.

I been trying with pandas to create tables but i get no output and when i export to excel i just get a single line in the excel file

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

source = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phone-Smartphone-Parts/43304/bn_151926?rt=nc&_pgn=1').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

items = soup.find('li', class_='s-item')



for items in soup.find_all('li', class_='s-item'):


    try:
        item_title = items.find('h3', class_='s-item__title').text
    except Exception as e:
        item_title = 'None'

    print(item_title)

    try:
        item_price = items.find('span', class_='s-item__price').text
    except Exception as e:
        item_price = 'None'

    print(item_price)

    try:
        item_desc = items.find('div', class_='s-item__summary').text
    except Exception as e:
        item_desc = 'None'

    print(item_desc)

    try:
        item_brand = items.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s-item__dynamicAttributes2').text
    except Exception as e:
        item_brand = 'None'

    print(item_brand)

    try:
        item_link = items.find('a', class_='s-item__link')['href']
    except Exception as e:
        item_link = 'None'

    print(item_link)

# I also dont know if the pandas code should be indented inside the loop or #outside of it btw, below is the panda table i been trying to create.

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Title', 'description', 'Price', 'Link'])

    df.loc[n, 'Title'] = item_title
    df.loc[n, 'description'] = item_desc
    df.loc[n, 'Price'] = item_price
    df.loc[n, 'Link'] = item_link    

    n+=1

df.head()
#nothing happens here =(
```

So i get the data pulled from the site, the loop is working but I just cant pull that into a table or a excel file.

Answer (score 0):

A little tweak on your code, the `item_title`, `item_desc`, `item_price` and `item_link` should be **lists**. So, everytime you get a value using the `items.find`, you have to append it to its respective list instead of storing it in a variable, named as such.

Secondly, you don't have to iterate the column name or use `loc`. The last part of your code should look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Title', 'description', 'Price', 'Link'])

df['Title'] = item_title
df['description'] = item_desc
df['Price'] = item_price
df['Link'] = item_link
```

Once you've declared the columns, all you have to do is give them the values, these values are in your lists obtained during iteration.

Hope this helps :)).